# edit .bat using cmake or cpack

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmake, environment-variables, cmake-custom-command

I made an installer for my software using cmake and cpack.
in the cpack installer the user chose where to install the software.
let's say `C:\Users\MySoftware`

all my `.exe` and a `python` file go in it using the Destination option of `cmake`.
using `cpack`, it adds `C:\Users\MySoftware` to my environment variable.
then all my .exe are usable from the window `cmd`.

I have a `.bat` which run the multiple `.exe` in some order with some options etc ...
and in the middle of it, it runs a python script.

```
python C:\HardPATH/mypython.py -i %var1% -m %var2% -t %var3% -o %var4% -I %var5% .
```

I am trying to modify C:\HardPath when using cmake or cpack

My problem is that I don't find a way to edit "HardPATH" using `cmake` or `cpack`, according to where the user choose to install the software.
and because it's a `.py` and not `.exe`, even if it's in the folder added to the env path it doesn't work.
I tried using `configure_file` but it's executed to soon, at configure step, so before the user choose the "HardPATH" using cpack installer. maybe something is possible using `add_custom_command` ? but I don't get how to change the hardPATH in the .bat using this command, or if it's possible.

Any idea how i could solve this "HardPATH" problem ?

```
  IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Windows)
    IF(Pack)
     INSTALL(TARGETS 
            exe1
            exe2
            etc
            DESTINATION bin)

     find_program(PYTHON "python")

    if (PYTHON)
     INSTALL(FILES mypython.py DESTINATION bin)
    endif()

   ELSE(Pack)
    INSTALL(TARGETS 
            exe1
            exe2
            etc
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)

    find_program(PYTHON "python")
    if (PYTHON)
      INSTALL(FILES mypython.py DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)
    endif()
  ENDIF(Pack)

  ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Windows)
```

and to add the path in the env variable, in the main cmakelist calling this one, I have:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "CPackExampleInstaller")
SET(CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH ON)
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

if I type `echo %PATH%`
I see where I chose to install mysoftware in it.

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.
>   0\libnvvp;C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Python36\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Pro
>   gram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\m
>   ingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;**C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testCode\bin**;;C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;D:\xxxx\Docker
>   Toolbox

and i can call the .exe within **C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testCode\bin** without typing the full path. but not the python

Comment: How about you post the code of the .bat file, then perhaps I can be clear on what you want.

Comment: sorry I thought it was clear enough. python C:\HardPATH/mypython.py -i %var1% -m %var2% -t %var3% -o %var4% -I %var5% . I am trying to modify C:\HardPath when using cmake or cpack

Comment: Then send the path as a variable and catch it using `%1` I cannot show you though because I do not have any of your code. Also, do not add code to comments, instead edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. which code do you want ? the cmakelists.txt ? the .bat file ? I don't understand

Comment: Yes, you want help with your code, so post some code.

Comment: yes but which one ? the cmakelist ?

Comment: Yes, please. I need to see how your processes fit together.

Comment: So you actually store the Hardpath as an environment variable?

Comment: yes it is an env variable.
if I do echo %PATH%, I have plenty, including HardPATH, but I don't know how to find it from the many in %PATH%

Comment: but if you add it to the path you do not have to call hardpath anymore..... You then just do `python mypython.py -I....` because mypython.py is in the path

Comment: no I tried it's not working. I was expecting it would work like this but it's not. it says the file doesn't exist. it's working for the .exe but not the .py

Comment: Do you call the batch file after the make? If not, you need to recall the batch to read from the newly set env

Comment: yes I call it after the make. I opened a new cmd prompt after the make as well. (I haven't restart the computer. but I thought opening a new cmd should be enough)

Comment: Does not seem right. Can you do echo %PATH% and copy the output to the question?

Comment: Just so you know, there are two ;; after the relevant path. `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testCode\bin;;`

Comment: yes I noticed, but it's added using CPack, I just give C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testCode\bin to it, I have no idea why there is two ;; and don't think I have a control on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/configure_file.html).

Instead of the final `.bat` with the hardcoded path, your source tree only contains a template for the final file:

```
rem File: foo.bat.in
python @MY_PATH@/mypython.py -i %var1% -m %var2% -t %var3% -o %var4% -I %var5% .
```

You then use CMake to generate the real batch file into the binary tree:

```
set(MY_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/python)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.bat.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.bat @ONLY)
```

Then you install the `.bat` file from the binary tree.

Note that this is still a *bad idea*. The convention is that files in the install tree are relocatable, so having hardcoded absolute paths anywhere in your install artifacts is not a nice thing to do and will likely upset your users. Better change your scripts so that they work with relative paths only.

Comment: thanks. this is what I was looking for. I am going to try soon (don't have access my computer for now). I am just afraid about the non relative path, I had some problem with cpack and this but I am going to try soon

Comment: so I have done this: set(MY_PATH $CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY/bin)
configure_file(Test.bat.in $CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY/bin/Test.bat @ONLY) but it doesn't work. the .bat does not appear in the directory selected by the user using the cpack interface

Comment: You need two steps, as described above: You configure to the build tree and install to the install tree. Do not attempt to cut corners by mixing the two.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. in my source, I have the .bat.in in which I set python @MY_PATH@/mypython.py etc ... 
I want MY_PATH to be the path specified by the user using cpack install. this variable is $CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY right ? and I want this .bat to go in the directory indicated by the path. so what you are saying is that I should do: set(MY_PATH $CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY/bin)  configure_file(Test.bat.in $CMAKE_BINARY_DIR/Test.bat @ONLY), and then INSTALL(FILES Test.bat DESTINATION bin) ? I am trying without sucess for now

Comment: I have python $CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY/mypython.py in the build directory after performing the cmake configuration and generation. and when I generate the cpack installer and install it doen't move the .bat where I want

Comment: is there a way to use configure_file or equivalent "inside" cpack ? because apparently here it modifies the .bat before the user choose where to install

Comment: is it possible to do something with add_custom_command which seems to be execute later than configure_file ? at build step.